# google sheet change background based on text to multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I learned to change background color base on cell text by column, but I need to do it column by column, does google sheets support apply a formula for multiple columns?

For example:

```
   A     B     C      D
1 Name   v1    v2     v3
2 Apple  Y     Y      Y
3 Orange N     N      Y
```

I can use below formula for one column:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2:D3,"Y")
```

I try to change it to a region as below but doesn't work:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2:D7,"Y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select range `B2:D7`.
Then, use this formula in Conditional formatting `custom formula`

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(B2:D7,"Y"))
```

OR put `Y` in `text is exactly`